# Why my rabbitMQ client can't connect?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to create RabbitMQ connection with server using TLSv1.2, but I have java.net.SocketException: Connection reset or javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (It looks like this exceptions are changing randomly).

It worked when I had TLSv1.0, but when server changed protocol it stopped working (even if I'm using the same cipher, port etc).

Is it possible to get this exceptions if vhost/other connection parameter is incorrect?

Before connection, I'm setting:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

Here is my configuration:

```
public ConnectionFactory get() throws IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, URISyntaxException {
    final ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();

    final SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext();

    cf.useSslProtocol(sslContext);

    final ConnectionSettings connectionSettings = getConnectionSettings(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

    cf.setHost(connectionSettings.getHost());
    cf.setPort(connectionSettings.getPort());
    cf.setVirtualHost(connectionSettings.getVirtualHost());
    //using cf.setUsername and cs.setPassword doesn't work

    cf.setSaslConfig(DefaultSaslConfig.EXTERNAL);
    cf.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);
    cf.setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(false);

    return cf;
}
```

And getSSLContext() method:

```
private SSLContext getSSLContext(){
    //SECURE_PROTOCOLE = "TLSv1.2"
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(SECURE_PROTOCOLE);

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    keystore.load(null, null); 

    final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keystore, null);


    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }
    } };

    sslContext.init(keyManagerWrapper(kmf),
            trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    return sslContext;   
    }
```

Exception occurs when I'm trying to create new connection:

```
this.connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactoryProvider().get();
this.connection = this.connectionFactory.newConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing TLS errors such as these with limited information is very difficult. You do not provide the following information which would be helpful:

- RabbitMQ version
- Erlang version
- Operating system platform and version for both RabbitMQ server and client
- Java version and Java client version

This line of code hints that you are running your client application on Windows:

```
KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY")
```

If you can provide the above information as well as a complete set of TLS/SSL certificates to reproduce the problem that would be ideal.

The RabbitMQ documentation also includes a [comprehensive TLS/SSL troubleshooting guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html).